# Why do I get undeclared inclusion error when using the lib as external library?

Tags: windows, bazel

I am trying to include an external library (glm) in my bazel build, but I get  undeclared inclusion the thing is I don't understand how to fix it and why, Because if I use the same BUILD script when I extract manually the library it builds fine.

I managed to make a very small repro of this problem, both the working case and the not working.

**The not working example**

My folder structure

- glmExtBuild

  - WORKSPACE
  - externals

    - glm.BUILD

This is my WORKSPACE file

```
new_http_archive(
  name = "glmExt",
  url = "https://github.com/g-truc/glm/archive/0.9.9.0.tar.gz",
  sha256 = "514dea9ac0099dc389cf293cf1ab3d97aff080abad55bf79d4ab7ff6895ee69c",
  strip_prefix = "glm-0.9.9.0",
  build_file = "externals/glm.BUILD",
)
```

This is my glm.BUILD file

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
  name= "glm",
  defines= ["GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL", "GLM_FORCE_RADIANS", 
  "GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE"],
  srcs=glob(["glm/**/*.cpp"]) + ["glm/detail/_fixes.hpp"],
  hdrs=glob(["glm/**/*.hpp"])+glob(["glm/**/*.h"]),
  includes = ["glm"],
  textual_hdrs = glob(["glm/**/*.inl"]),
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And this is the errors that I get when I run

```
bazel build @glmExt//:glm --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug

ERROR: C:/users/...../external/glmExt/BUILD.bazel:121:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@glmExt//:glm':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/glmExt/glm/detail/glm.cpp': 
'external/glmext/glm/detail/_fixes.hpp'
'external/glmext/glm/detail/setup.hpp'
'external/glmext/glm/simd/platform.h'
'external/glmext/glm/fwd.hpp'
'external/glmext/glm/detail/setup.hpp'
'external/glmext/glm/detail/type_int.hpp'
'external/glmext/glm/detail/setup.hpp'
'external/glmext/glm/detail/type_float.hpp'
...
```

**The working example:**

My folder structure

- glmBuild2

  - WORKSPACE
  - BUILD
  - glmSrc

    - https://github.com/g-truc/glm/archive/0.9.9.0.tar.gz extracted here

My WORKSPACE file is empty

And this is my BUILD file

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
  name= "glm",
  defines= ["GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL", "GLM_FORCE_RADIANS", "GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE"],
  srcs=glob(["glmSrc/glm/**/*.cpp"]) + ["glmSrc/glm/detail/_fixes.hpp"],
  hdrs=glob(["glmSrc/glm/**/*.hpp"])+glob(["glmSrc/glm/**/*.h"]),
  includes = ["glmSrc"],
  textual_hdrs = glob(["glmSrc/glm/**/*.inl"]),
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Then when running the build command it finished successfully.

```
PS D:\......\glmBuild2> bazel build :glm --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug
INFO: Analysed target //:glm (1 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Compiling glmSrc/glm/detail/glm.cpp:
glmSrc/glm/detail/glm.cpp(4): warning C4005: 'GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL': macro redefinition
glmSrc/glm/detail/glm.cpp(4): note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL'
Target //:glm up-to-date:
  C:/users/.../execroot/__main__/bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/libglm.a
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.830s, Critical Path: 1.30s
INFO: 3 processes, local.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4 total actions
```

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks

Update:

```
bazel version
Build label: 0.14.0
Build target: bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Jun 1 13:06:29 2018 (1527858389)
Build timestamp: 1527858389
Build timestamp as int: 1527858389
```

Bazel issue:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5485

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first example on linux, with bazel 0.15.0, and all worked once I added "." into `includes` attribute of `glm`. Do you have a possibility to test it on linux? Is it windows-only issue then? Which bazel version do you use?

Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: I tried with include = "." and it doesn't work. Also, I am on windows and I don't have access to linux. Wow, 0.15.0 just got released. I'll try it.

Comment: I have the same issue on 0.15.0.

Comment: I don't know how the check for includes work but it seems it only look for exact matches. all the headers are set in the BUILd script relative to the external workspace.
glm/detail/glm.cpp does #include <glm/glm.hpp> 
then glm/glm.hpp does #include "detail/_fixes.hpp" but bazel says it can't find. i think it is there at least twice, in the srcs and hdrs but as glm/detail/_fixes.hpp.
I don't know the algorithm used but for bazel glm/detail/fixes.hpp != detail/_fixes.hpp

Comment: include attribute only adds -isystem, but you can try to juggle with https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.include_prefix and strip_include_prefix which add -I.

Comment: Ya I tried it already, but what confuses me is that the script is working when not as an external, and it works on Linux, so it should work like this.

Comment: Ya I tried it already, I tried to strip the glm part but it was still not working (in 0.14.0), but what confuses me is that the script is working when not as an external, and it works on Linux, so it should work like this.
I'd like to find the actual test, also the fact that the error output path corresponding to the generated workspace is confusing. I wonder if my build script need to be made in respect of the generated workspace and BUILD?